# International characters in pyodbc - ODBC python library

Tags: database, python, libraries

I'm using pyodbc to connect to my *.mdb files and store them in a sqlite / spatialite database for further work and analysis. I'm passing DSN like this:

```
DSN="Driver={%s};DBQ=%s;"%(self.find_mdb_driver(),self.mdbPath)
```

and then:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN)
```

Problem is, that when I try to pass path with international characters cp1250 "čžš" I get error:

```
table=cursor.fetchall()
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u017e' in position 111: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any pointers to this problem ?

Comment: What Python version do you use? Can you create a minimal example with directly passed parameters instead of the unshown (and probably hard to show) self-based references?

Answer (score 0):

Minimal example of the problem:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pyodbc

if __name__ == '__main__':

    DSN_1="Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\ep5065\Documents\GREDOS\Gredos 2015\Analize omrežja\Komen NOS 2015\Končno stanje\Analiza stanja Komen.mdb;"

    DSN_2="Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\ep5065\Documents\GREDOS\Gredos 2015\Gredos modeli\9_2_2015\EP_9_2_2015_v1.mdb;"
    conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN_1)
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select * from Branch')
    table=cursor.fetchall()

    for line in table:
        print line
```

If I use DSN_1 it breaks with above mentioned error, if I use DSN_2 it happily spits table contents.